# EF Core TimeStamp is always incremental?

Tags: entity-framework

I understood that the `[TimeStamp]` attribute is used for optimistic control.

Can I assume that it is always incremental?

So that I can use this value to check which version of data is the latest (when there are discrepancies) between the same DB which had been mirrored to another server.

I know this is not foolproof but as long as it is incremental, it is good enough for my usage.

Comment: A SQL Server Timestamp/Rowversion column behaves like that, and is often used for that purpose.  Although it's not necessary to add a column to the table if you turn on Change Tracking, which will also track deletes.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Thanks. You mean Change Tracking in EF or SQL? As far as I know, I need to use TimeStamp in order to achieve Optimistic Concurrency. But now I need it to use this value to sync value between two DB.